how can i query post on metaPost using drizzle?
export const postMetas = mysqlTable("wp_postmeta", {
  meta_id: bigint("meta_id", {
    mode: "number",
  })
    .primaryKey()
    .autoincrement(),
  post_id: bigint("post_id", {
    mode: "number",
  }).notNull(),
  meta_key: varchar("meta_key", {
    length: 255,
  }).notNull(),
  meta_value: text("meta_value"),
});

its my postMetas schema
export const postsRelations = relations(posts, ({ one, many }) => ({
  author: one(users, { fields: [posts.post_author], references: [users.ID] }),
  postMetas: many(postMetas),
  termRelationships: many(termRelationships),
}));

// Define postMetas relations
export const postMetasRelations = relations(postMetas, ({ one }) => ({
  post: one(posts, { fields: [postMetas.post_id], references: [posts.ID] }),
}));

i build posts and postMetas relations
const data = await db.query.postMetas.findMany({
    limit,
    offset,
    columns: {
      post_id: true,
    },
    with: {
      post: true,
    },
  });

  console.log("====================================");
  console.log(data);
  console.log("====================================");

but when i hit the query when i want to get post by post meta its error
⨯ Internal error: Error: Unknown column 'postMetas.post_id' in 'where clause'
    at PromisePool.query (./node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:356:22)
    at MySql2PreparedQuery.execute (./node_modules/drizzle-orm/mysql2/session.js:58:33)
    at QueryPromise.execute (./node_modules/drizzle-orm/mysql-core/query-builders/query.js:115:27)
    at QueryPromise.then (./node_modules/drizzle-orm/query-promise.js:26:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
digest: "2602222953"

i was create a same schema for wordpress database and now my db moved to myphpadmin but it doesn't work
